# ASP.NET MVC Temp Data and RedirectToAction in web form

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, web-farm, tempdata

In ASP.NET MVC from one controller in one area I am using:

```
TempData["Model"] = model;
```

then `RedirectToAction` to pass the model to another controller in another area. In the controller action method I immediately pull the data back out of the model.

I am concerned that if I deploy to a web farm then `TempData`'s use of session state will cause issues but am not sure if I can get away with it in this case because I immediately pull the model out of `TempData` again  in the action method I pass to?

Comment: [Similiar questions](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=tempdata%20web%20farm%20site:stackoverflow.com)

Answer (score 2):

You are right to be concerned, a RedirectToAction sends the client a 302 message containing a url of the redirected resource.  This is then the clients responsibilty to create a new request to the redirected resource.  There is no guarantee this resource will be served by the original server.  The fact that the request is pulled immediately from TempData makes no difference to this approach, at some point it is going to error.

You need to have some means of managing sessions. You could configure [HTTP session affinity](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tconte/archive/2013/09/19/advanced-cookie-based-session-affinity-with-application-request-routing.aspx) so that requests served from a server will always return to the originating server.

You could use [cookies for session state](http://volaresystems.com/Blog/post/2011/06/30/Sessionless-MVC-without-losing-TempData) or implement a [session state provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms178587%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

This [blog post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/LoadBalancingAndASPNET.aspx) is also a good start on the overview of the options.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using InProc session state you might run into problems because in the redirect you could be sent to another server where the same session will not be available.

Two possible options are  to either implement a [cookie based TempData](http://blog.appharbor.com/2012/4/04/cookietempdataprovider-for-asp-net) provider or switch to another [session-state mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). Note that cookie based TempData is completely visible to users, though there are implementations where you encrypt the data.

Answer (score 0):

Try with cooke based instead of session tempdata

See below link

http://volaresystems.com/Blog/post/2011/06/30/Sessionless-MVC-without-losing-TempData

Answer (score 0):

Avoid the use of TempData all together. If you are sending your model in the redirection then use something like

```
RedirectToAction("MyAction", new {model = myModel});

public actionresult MyAction(model model)
{
    /// Mode Code
    return View(MyView, model);
}
```

Assuming that you controller action will take the model as parameter.